# Website cached in Google with page category - Wordpress .

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

Our Website url structure is something like this :- `www.example.com/website/xyz.htm`

Our Website cached in Google something like this :- `www.example.com/page/1` to `www.example.com/page/32` but when i open this url, it's pointing me to the home page. We have used Wordpress CMS.

We have not created these things in our website. We do not understand, how it happened.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wordpress [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) Plugin. This will give you the functionality to remove the caching in Google Search.

After disabled the `/page/`option, you need to resubmit the sitemap xml in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might have used a plugin for getting WP SEF url for your WP pages to appear as HTML pages. Use some other latest , compatible and popular plugin  to convert WP pages as HTML pages.

Google sometimes does not understand your site perfectly at all time due to the modification you done in your site.

So create an account in [google analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/) and verify it with your site then remove all listed pages and rebuild it once again by submitting new sitemap